# How to show compiler errors in problems pane when using Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cytoscape

The way that I see compiler errors is right clicking my pom.xml and clicking "run as --> maven install" and a console output shows compiler errors.

Is it possible to make eclipse detect compiler errors in real-time and show them in the problems pane like it does when you are not using Maven?

Comment: have you got build automatically check box checked?? Enable it and try

Answer (score 0):

[image]

have you got build automatically check box checked?? Enable it and try